# Is it possible to create a DataSnap server but with a FMX form instead of a VCL form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, datasnap

When we create a new DataSnap Server with the wizard, we have the choice to create a VCL form server. I just want to know if it is possible to create a Datasnap server with a FMX form instead of a VCL form.

Comment: Why would which GUI framework a *server* application uses matter? (Just curious.) GUI is a graphical user interface, and servers don't typically interact much with users; they're designed to run on a *server* and respond to client requests.

Comment: I can't see why not.  The VCL is probably to do with the MainForm created so no reason why you couldn't - eg if you want to run the Server on a MAC for any reason.  Create a DS server using the wizard, then a new FMX HD app, then just copy the ServerContainer and ServerMethod units created by the wizard into the FMX app and see if it works

Comment: @Ken: Embarcadero doesn't like services... or daemons. That's why datasnap server are implemented as GUI applications and the wizard tries to create a main form. It's an old issue and show how much a proper, modern implementation of Datasnap has been neglected.

Comment: @MadHatter: It still doesn't matter. The wizard generates interfaces that can be copied from the VCL version and pasted directly into the FMX version, AFAIK. So you create the VCL version with the wizard, start a new FMX project, copy the relevant code from the first to the second, make any adjustments to the uses clause, and you're done.

Comment: @Ken: no, for example a true DCOM service is very different from what Delphi implements. The only way AFAIK to have a real DCOM service with Delphi without implementing yourself is using SvCom. Probably with dbExpress Datasnap it's easier because it doesn't rely on DCOM, but the very fact Delphi requires you silly step and implement a server on Windows in ways different than a service show you how little it thought about it. On *nix systems it should be implemented as a non-GUI application that can be easily demonized. But Emb teams can't think outside desktop apps, it looks.

Comment: I've tonight as a curiosity tried this, and despite some warnings/protestations from Delphi it appeared to work fine. That said, given that it's unlikely that you'll want much if any of an integrated UI in a service application, I question wanting to do this in the first place.  (Aside, Datasnap servers don't necessarily get created as normal VCL applications with a mainform for some time already -- at least since XE and certainly on XE5 you can have the wizard start you off with a skeleton OS service application.  Works fine via the SCM and obviously has no UI.)